# Windows 8 bottom app bar

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, application-bar

I've been trying to get an `App bar` implemented in a `WinRT metro app` (`C#` / `XAML`), but don't know where to begin. I've tried using the `<ApplicationBar/>` tag and I get a `Type not found` error.

There's no help online, could someone update this post with the answer so that it'll serve as a reference to other programmers as well?

There's only a `JavaScript` sample which isn't of much help.

Comment: you can follow this tutorial:
[Quickstart: adding app bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh781232.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
<AppBar
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Button
        AutomationProperties.Name="Play"
        Style="{StaticResource PlayAppBarButtonStyle}"
        Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />
</AppBar>
```

– you would put that in the layout root grid of your page.

*EDIT

Note: According to documentation - you should put it in [Page.BottomAppBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.aspx) property, although at least in Windows 8 Consumer Preview - it works fine when used in any Grid, which is convenient if your UI isn't tightly coupled to a Page control.

*EDIT 2, [response from MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1044f2fb-bc55-4391-ac82-02c5d5e75970/):

The recommended approach is to use the Page.BottomAppBar/TopAppBar properties.

- There are known hit-testing issues in the Consumer Preview if AppBars are added without using these properties
- The AppBars do not use the proper animations if they are added without using these properties
- If AppBars are added as children of arbitrary elements then it's easier for multiple controls to attempt to create/modify AppBars, resulting in an inconsistent user experience

*EDIT 3

The CustomAppBar in [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) can be used anywhere, animates based on Vertical/Horizontal-Alignment, can have other content overlaid on top of it and also has a CanOpen property that allows to block it from opening.

Comment: In WinRT you have to put it inside the Page.BottomAppBar or Page.TopAppBar properties. I suggest you correct your answer to avoid down votes =).

Comment: @carlo is right.  they changed it between dev and consumer previews

Comment: They did? I never noticed. I just put it in a grid in all my applications and it just works. What if I don't have a page? I was actually planning to stop using Microsoft's Frame/Page controls and replace them with mine because theirs suck (limited features). Do you mean I will need to build my own AppBar too? For now just putting it in a Grid works. I'll look for documentation that might indicate that this would stop working in future builds...

Answer (score 1):

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="Sample Text" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```